# Generating 3D tables which are plottable

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I construct a 3D table of datapoints `{x,y,z=f(x,y)}` in the most natural way I can think of,

```
data = Table[{x, y, x + y}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

where for the sake of illustration I chose `z=x+y`. As a result I get

```
{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 2}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}}
```

which contains a lot of unnecessary curly brackets. In fact, when I try to plot the table in the most natural way I can think of, i.e., using `ListPlot3D[data]`, I get an empty plot (of course `ListPlot3D` is confused by the brackets). I have two questions:

1. Can you name a case where those extra brackets are useful?
2. What is the simplest way of plotting the table above?

I am aware one could use `Plot3D` to plot `f(x,y)` over a grid of x and y, but in many cases it comes handy to have the data stored in a table for intermediate manipulations.

Comment: `Flatten[data, 1]` will remove the "extra" layer of braces and yield a structure that can be plotted with `ListPlot3D` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your case the braces are not necessary. However, you can easily get ride of them:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, x + y}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}], 1]
ListPlot3D[data]

(* {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 2}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2,
   0, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 4}} *)
```

On the other hand, if you imply x and y values and store only f[x,y] then the braces indicate rows (you need at least 12 data points). E.g:

```
data = Table[x + y, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]
ListPlot3D[data]

(*{{0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to plot is this:

```
data = Table[{x, y, x + y}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]

ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Flatten[data, 1]` will remove the "extra" layer of braces and yield a structure that can be plotted with `ListPlot3D` directly:

```
table = Table[{x, y, x + y}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}];
flat = Flatten[table, 1]
ListPlot3D[flat]
```

[image: 3D plot from flattened data]

To answer your first point regarding the presence of those "extra" braces: the braces may not be useful in your application, but in my opinion it makes sense for `Table` to produce that result. For instance, consider the generation of a truth table for `Xor`:

```
TableForm[
  Table[Xor[x, y], {x, {True, False}}, {y, {True, False}}],
  TableHeadings -> ConstantArray[{True, False}, 2]
]
```

[image: truth table for Xor]